# Error When Using Android CaptureRequest.CONTROL_ZOOM_RATIO

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I just updated my project to Androidx and upgraded to SDK version 30, but when I want to adjust my zoom value I got

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field CONTROL_ZOOM_RATIO of type Landroid/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest$Key; in class Landroid/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
```

The code that went wrong is：

```
builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_ZOOM_RATIO,newZoom);
```

Comment: What type of builder is being used here? `builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_ZOOM_RATIO,newZoom);` Are you able to provide a larger snippet, please?

Answer (score 1):

CONTROL_ZOOM_RATIO is supported starting from API level 30. Did you run you app on the device that has API level 30 or higher ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I found that it was 29 that's why it won't work.